# WiX 3.6 patch file XML

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.6

Where do I include the Upgrade/Target Image in the following Patch XML?  I need to include the Validate ProductId element which is why I cannot use my previous XML structure.

```
<Patch AllowRemoval="yes"
    Classification="Update"
    Comments="Patch"
    Description="Patch"
    DisplayName="Patch"
    Manufacturer="..."
    MoreInfoURL="http://..."
    TargetProductName="Szenario Rechner"
    Codepage="1252">

    <Media Id="1000"
           Cabinet="Patch.cab"
           EmbedCab="yes"
           Source="Cab1" >
        <PatchBaseline Id="RTM">
            <Validate ProductId="no" />
        </PatchBaseline>
    </Media>
    <PatchFamily Id='pf1'
                 Version='1.2.7.0'
                 Supersede='yes'>

        <ComponentRef Id="Szenariorechner" />
    </PatchFamily>
</Patch>
```

Below is my previous patch XML.

```
<PatchCreation Id="224C316C-5894-4771-BABF-21A3AC1F75FF"
               CleanWorkingFolder="yes"
               WholeFilesOnly="yes">
    <PatchInformation Description="Patch 1.0.4475.23974"
                      Comments="Patch 1.0.4475.23974"
                      ShortNames="no"
                      Languages="1033"
                      Compressed="yes"
                      Manufacturer="..." />
    <PatchMetadata AllowRemoval="yes"
                   Description="Patch 1.0.4475.23974"
                   ManufacturerName="..."
                   TargetProductName="Update"
                   MoreInfoURL="http://"
                   Classification="Update"
                   DisplayName="Patch 1.0.4475.23974" />
    <Family DiskId="2"
            MediaSrcProp="Sample"
            Name="Update"
            SequenceStart="600">

        <UpgradeImage SourceFile="C:\new.msi"
                      Id="PatchUpgrade">
            <TargetImage SourceFile="C:\old.msi"
                         Order="2"
                         Id="PatchUpgrade"
                         IgnoreMissingFiles="no" />
        </UpgradeImage>
    </Family>
    <PatchSequence PatchFamily="SamplePatchFamily"
                   Sequence="1.0.4475.23974"
                   Supersede="yes" />
</PatchCreation>
```

Comment: btw, don't share the exact GUIDs you use for your installation - someone can take your sample literally as is, and there's a bit higher chance of GUID conflicts than usual :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old patch authoring refers to the patch creation [using Patch Creation Properties](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/patch_building.htm). The one you are referencing as a new [uses purely WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_patching.htm). As you can see, [UpgradeImage](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_upgradeimage.htm)/[TargetImage](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_targetimage.htm) pairs are not required for the later one.

Instead, you should author a [TargetProductCodes](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_targetproductcodes.htm) element directly under the [Patch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_patch.htm) root and add a number of [TargetProductCode](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_targetproductcode.htm) elements as its direct children:

```
<TargetProductCodes>
   <TargetProductCode Id="PUT-PRODUCT-CODE-HERE" />
   <TargetProductCode Id="PUT-PRODUCT-CODE-HERE" />
   <TargetProductCode Id="PUT-PRODUCT-CODE-HERE" />
   ...
   <TargetProductCode Id="PUT-PRODUCT-CODE-HERE" />
</TargetProductCodes>
```

When you build a patch, you feed the torch.exe with both base and updated MSI (or WIXPDB) files to generate a diff. Hope it's helpful. I suggest you to look through the "purely WiX" approach once again to understand it better.

Comment: one more thing.  can you patch multiinstance using the old way over patching (Patch creation properties) ?

Comment: Why not? According to the TargetProductCode element description in manual, "When using the PatchCreation element, if the Id attribute value is '*' or this element is not authored, the product codes of all products referenced by the TargetImages element are used." However, I didn't try that approach, to be honest - you'll have to play with it first